# Godot's logs : On error can I hide the location in cpp file?

Tags: godot

**Scenario:**

- create a .gd script (i.e. in GDScript)
- Make it so that the script outputs an error to the Godot console.
  More specifically: Make it so that the error is not a crash inside the low-level c++ code, but strictly something in the GDscript. For example, this kind of instruction: **assert(false)** .

This does not need to involve c++ in any way. Therefore in my opinion **the location of this game error in the c++ codebase is irrelevant.** All I want to know is in which **GDScript** this happened.

Yet, Godot says in which cpp file the error "occurred". Every time, it creates an extra line in the logs.

[image]

**It slows down my work a lot:** *Every time,* I need to read twice: First my brain makes me read that incorrect location (muscle memory: if the logs give you a stack trace, you look at the stack trace!). It takes one or two seconds for me to discard that line and read what's above: The "real" error with the "real" location of the problem (the GDscript).

**Is there a way to *not* display the cpp file location** whenever an error occurs in a GDScript?

Comment: I don't think there is such option. You can bring this up for discussion at [discussions](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment.